# How do you pass in a dynamic form name in redux form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

Im trying to use this code to pass a dynamic form name into reduxForm.

Here is the code that I found:

```
let FormAddress = compose(connect((state, props) => ({form: props.form})), reduxForm({destroyOnUnmount: false, asyncBlurFields: []}))(ValidationForm);
```

From this article:
https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/603#issuecomment-254271319

But I'm not really sure whats going on.

This is how I'm currently doing it:

```
const formName = 'shippingAddress';
const form = reduxForm({
  form: formName
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CityStateZip);
```

But I would like to be able to pass it in using props, like this:

```
const formName = 'shippingAddress';
const form = reduxForm({
  form: props.form
  // validate
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CityStateZip);
```

But when I try that, it complains that it doesnt know what props is - because I believe it's outside the scope of the function above.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Personal suggestion here - but I've had much more success **not** using redux form. It is awesome at what it does but when you starting needing to add complexity from your app to it, it becomes difficult to work with. I know people have had great success with it, but something like the problem you are having here takes 2 seconds to do if you aren't depending on redux form...

Comment: Just wondering if my answer worked for you

Answer (score 43):

The parent component which calling the `FormAddress` component should send the name of the form in props as `props.form`:

```
var formId="SomeId"
<FormAddress form={formId} />

// and in your FormAddress component have 
const form = reduxForm({
  //no need to put form again here as we are sending form props.
});
```

This works for me.

Comment: I like this because in my use case the name is really a concern of the parent rendering it.  Now my form can be more general and does not need to derive its name.

Comment: Nice and simple

Answer (score 24):

That snippet basically uses the `compose` function from `redux` library. Here's something you can try...

`<FormAddress name="shippingAddress" />`

So in your `components/FormAddress.js` file

```
import React from 'react';
import { compose } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

class FormAddress extends React.Component { ... }

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    return {
        form: ownProps.name,
        // other props...
    }
}

export default compose(
    connect(mapStateToProps),
    reduxForm({
        //other redux-form options...
    })
)(FormAddress);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Upvoted this as a more complete answer, because ownProps as a parameter in mapStateToProps allows the user to access the specific name of the form from the redux store more consistently throughout the component using the "this.props"