# accessing formsection children form values in parent (redux-form)

Tags: redux-form

ParentForm.js

```
<FormSection name="ChildRequestForm">
   <ChildForm />
</FormSection>
```

on form submission in ParentForm, it should get values from ChildForm component, this works fine.

But once the ChildForm component has a reduxForm connected
ex:

```
ChildForm = reduxForm({
    form: 'ChildRequestForm'
})(ChildForm);
```

then the parent form will no longer able to retrieve values of the child form on submit.

I had to wrap the child component with reduxForm as the form requires to dispatch 'change' function and requires access to formvalueSelector

Sandbox Link
https://codesandbox.io/s/jj1mk114n5

any help?

Comment: I'm confused; since the parent uses FormSection (which is from redux-form) does that mean the parent is also managed by redux-form?

Comment: yes, the parent is also wrapped with reduxForm()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Childform should have the same name as parent form (in your example it is 'foo'). So to make the child form name dynamic, pass a formname prop to your child component and make use of it using mapstatetoprops ownprops.

By this way, you can reuse the child component with parent formname, whenever it is needed.

refer to dis
[How do you pass in a dynamic form name in redux form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40509754/how-do-you-pass-in-a-dynamic-form-name-in-redux-form)